# Ошибка после подключения библиотеки zip4j: Cannot resolve method 'extractAll' in 'ZipFile'

Tags: java, javafx, архивация

Пишу прогу и мне надо, чтобы после скачивания зип архива он сразу распаковывался.

Я решил взять код [из вопроса на engSO: Java ZIP - how to unzip folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10633595/java-zip-how-to-unzip-folder)

Импортировал библиотеку `zip4J`. Но почему-то не работает метод `extractAll`, и если навести на него курсор, появляется сообщение: `Cannot resolve method 'extractAll' in 'ZipFile'`.

Помогите пожалуйста.

```java
String source = "folder/source.zip";
String destination = "folder/source/";
try {
    ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(source);
    zipFile.extractAll(destination);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Это означает, что вы скорей всего снова некорректно прописали зависимость на библиотеку в вашем проекте.

Answer (score 0):

Как именно вы импортировали zip4j? Если пользуетесь maven то добавляйте тогда в pom

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>net.lingala.zip4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>zip4j</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Но судя по ошибке, вы импортировали библиотеку `java.util.zip.ZipFile;` которая не имеет такого метода как `extractAll()`
Отсюда и ошибка. Импортируйте нужную библиотеку и все будет в порядке